# Not able to paginate through records

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is snippet for the controller,

```
function email($start = 0) {

    $result = $this -> admintools -> get_email_errors();
    if ($result) {
        $data['email'] = $result;
    }

    $data['header'] = $this -> load -> view('includes/header', '', true);
    $data['footer'] = $this -> load -> view('includes/footer', $data, true);
    $data['menu_system_errors'] = $this -> load -> view('includes/menu_system_errors', $data, true);

    //$config['total_rows'] = $this -> db -> query($query);
    $config['base_url'] = '/admin/email';
    $config['total_rows'] = 1000;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    for ($i = $start; $i < $start + $config['per_page']; $i++) {
        if (isset($data_paging[$i])) {
            $data['email']= $data_paging[$i];
        }
    }

    $this -> pagination -> initialize($config);

    $this -> load -> view('/admin/email', $data);

}
```

and this is the **view**,

```
<?=$header
?>
<?=$menu_system_errors
?>

<style>
    .alpha-link {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

</style>
<h1>System Errors EMail</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Marketer ID</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>IP </th>

            <th>Received Date</th>
            <th>From Domain</th>
            <th>Subject</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <? foreach ($systemerrors_email as $systemerror) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$systemerror->marketerID
        ?></td>
        <td><?=$systemerror->ip
        ?></td>

        <td></td>
        <td><?=$systemerror->received
        ?></td>
        <td><?=$systemerror->fromDomain
        ?></td>
        <td><?=$systemerror->subject
        ?></td>

    </tr>
    <? }?>
</table>
<?echo $this -> pagination -> create_links();?>
```

The problem is it creates the pagination links but displays the same record, like only 10 rows but not whole of them. Is there any problem?

I am getting the records through a query using SELECT and JOIN.

Comment: Normally you do pagination at the database level so you don't fetch however many zillions of records there are and throw away all but the X-per-page you want to display.

Comment: You should include a LIMIT clause in your mySQL query and utilize the offset feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what config keys do what in order to get pagination to work.

`$config['total_rows']` defines the total amount of rows you want shown;

`$config['per_page']` defines how many you want  shown per page.

The reason you're seeing 10 results shown is because your `per_page` value is set to 10, if you want more, change it to the value you want.  Also, shouldn't your `$start` variable in your controller be set to `$this->uri->segment(3)`?  Since it relies on the the URL parameter, you're not allowing your loop to start from the next portion of rows -- you're basically forcing it to display the first ten queries.  If you set this variable so that it relies on something dynamic, you'd be able to get other data.